# How to get custom post_author?

Tags: plugin-development, users, author, email, wp-insert-post

I have a post type that inserts email as a post. I also created users according to those emails.
This is how I added my post type.

```
$post_array = array( 
                'post_content'  => $mail['body'], 
                'post_title'    => $mail['header']->subject,
                'post_type'     => 'my-post-type',
                'post_author'   =>  $user_name,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'meta_input'    => array(   
                    'User'      => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),
                    'From'      => preg_replace('~[<>]~', '', strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<')),
                    'Email'     => $mail['header']->Date,
                    'ticket_id' => preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->message_id, '@',true)),   
                    ),
                );
                    wp_insert_post( $post_array );
```

This is how I added the users:

```
if(email_exists($email)){
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'username', $email, True);  
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'email', $user, True);
 }
    else{
         $userdata = array(
        'user_login'    => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),
        'user_pass'     => '',
        'user_nicename' => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),   
        'display_name'  => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),
        'user_email'    => strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<'),
        'role'          => 'support_customer',
    );
    wp_insert_user($userdata);
}
```

Below is the code of how I added the user role:

```
$result= add_role('support_customer', __(
    'Support Customer', 'faqpress'),
array(
                    'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
                    'edit_posts'   => true,
                    'delete_posts' => true, // Use false to explicitly deny
                    'publish_posts' => true,    
                ));
```

Now I want the post to have the author the same as the user I just created.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Yes, All the users are created with the role `support_customer` and appear in my backend.

Comment: No, they don't appear in the Author dropdown.

Comment: I did create the Support Customer role as you suggested and it still is the same.
And for the plugin you suggested doesn't work with my PHP version.

Comment: I also created the user role for the users to `author` just to see if the users get the `author` to the post. But, it again does not work.

Comment: Try [this simple plugin](https://pastebin.com/bgMeTaxy) - save it as `wpse-401000.php` and put the file in the `wp-content/plugins` folder, then activate the plugin, and see what the "Status" on the plugin page says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your if-else block, I see there's a `$post_id` variable, so if it's the ID of the post that you want to assign to the user you're creating, then you could just call [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) in your `else` block, i.e. right after you create the user.

So just replace the `wp_insert_user($userdata);` in your code with this:

```php
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'          => $post_id,
        'post_author' => $user_id,
    ) );
}
```